# How to make eslint resolve paths mapped in jsconfig

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, eslint

In my nextjs project I have mapped path in `jsconfig.json` to make easy absolute imports

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

My import paths look like this
`import { VIEW } from '@/src/shared/constants';`

My `eslintrc.js` has settings specified as

```
module.exports = {
    ... ,
    settings: {
        "import/resolver": {
          alias: {
            extensions: [".js"],
            map: ["@", "."]
          }
        }
      }
}
```

I am still getting the error saying can't resolve "@/what/ever/my/path/is"

How do I make eslint realize the jsconfig path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was using babel-eslint as my parser in eslintrc. While searching, I realized I need to add `babel-plugin-module-resolver` in babelrc to resolve the modules. In this file we can define our mapped paths which are there in our jsconfig.

Hence adding the following plugin in the babelrc file compiled my code successfully.

```
[
    "module-resolver",
    {
        "alias": {
          "@": "./"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [the docs for eslint-import-resolver-alias](https://github.com/johvin/eslint-import-resolver-alias#usage), the `map` property should be an array of arrays, so try this:

```
module.exports = {
    ... ,
    settings: {
        "import/resolver": {
          alias: {
            extensions: [".js"],
            map: [ ["@", "."] ]
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Also, double-check that you actually have `eslint-import-resolver-alias` installed - it's easy to forget!

Comment: The plugin is installed, i tried doing it with array as well. Still the same problem, it cant resolve the path.